# Stuck - Favorite TV Show Logic grid (repost)

Tags: logic-grid

I was asked to repost and offer the source. I found this on:https://slideplayer.com/slide/8573924/

Four friends (Al, Gary, Mike, & Roger) each have a favorite TV show. Oddly enough, while the four are close friends, their interest in TV shows is so different that none of the friends has the same favorite. In fact, each favorite show (Explorer, FBI, Family Tides, & Z-Files) airs on a different night (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, & Wednesday) and at a different time (7pm, 8pm, 9pm or 10pm).

Determine the name of each friend, the title of their favorite TV show, and the day of the week and time that the show airs, based on the following requirements:

1. The person who enjoyed the TV show, FBI, doesn’t watch it on Sunday night. The TV show, Explorer, aired at 7 pm, but it wasn’t Mike’s favorite show.
2. Family Tides wasn’t Al’s favorite TV show.
3. Roger’s favorite TV show aired at 10 pm, but not on Wednesday night.
4. The TV show that aired on Tuesday night is The Z-Files.
5. Mike doesn’t watch a TV show at 9 pm. Gary doesn’t watch TV on Sunday night.
6. The TV show, Family Tides, aired an hour after the show that Gary liked but an hour before the show that aired on Monday night.